# GStreamer TCP streaming from Raspberry Pi to Android

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream the h264 video from raspberry pi camera to an android device using gstreamer and netcat.
I'm currently able to stream the video from raspberry using this:

```
//ON RASPBERRY
raspivid -t 0 -hf -n -h 480 -w 640 -fps 15 -o - | nc -l -p 5001
```

And receiving the stream in windows using

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.0.14 port=5001 ! queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
```

And this works well.

Then I tried to receive the stream in windows with a simple C application found in the Gstreamer example folder. And this works well too.

Now my goal is to receive the stream on an android device, using the gstreamer libraries. I'm able to compile and run the 5 included tutorials, but I can't correctly modify tutorial 3 to make it receiving the stream.
I'm creating the pipeline in this way:

```
 data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("tcpclientsrc host=192.168.2.205 port=5001 ! queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false", &error);
```

But it returns the following error:

> Error received from element tcpclientsrc1: Could not open resource for reading

Thanks for any help

Comment: shot in dark: maybe port is used by some other app? have you tried other ports

Comment: Thanks for your sudgestion but it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to add the Internet permission to my manifest.xml.